# Algorithm cycle removal

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an undirected graph G = (V, E) with non-negative weights w_e. I am trying find acyclic after removing a set of edges.
I tried calculate a MST to get the minor w_e in spanning tree. But it is not working.
Can someone help me?

Comment: MST usually means **minimum** spanning tree. I think all you need to do is find the **maximum** spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you gave enough detail in your question, consider given several illustrative examples to shore up the ambiguity in your question.

Given what you asked, it sounds like what you are actually trying to do is to reinvent a variant of the [Minimum Cost Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) problem. Since all your weights `w_i >= 0` are non-negative, create the MCF graph with the negative weight edges `-S + w_i <= 0` where `S = (sum of all w_i)`, give each edge a capacity of `1`, then run the MCF algorithm on that graph which will yield an acyclic graph.

The proof is simple:

Assume that there exists a cycle once MCF terminates. But then, since all weights are negative that cycle must be negative, contradicting the optimality condition of MCF. This implies there can exist no cycle once MCF terminates.

---

The choice of `-S+w_i` will directly lead to the flow that minimized the total cost of flow `w_i` used in constructing the acyclic graph, implying you have the

> the lightest set of edges E′ ⊆ E, such that G is acyclic after removing E′.

Note practically speaking, you may come across issues of bit depth if your graph is huge and `S` is a massive number. In this case, you may have to use an implementation of MCF that allows arbitriary bit-depth to correctly solve your problem. Alternatively, one could use `S=max(w_i)` and obtain the same result.

---

It should be noted that since your case uses undirected graphs, the MCF problem has to be constructed as an undirected MCF instance. This is atypical, and requires special treatment, but is completely manageable using the standard directed MCF formulation. A detailed discussion of undirected vs directed MCF problems and how they are related and how the undirected case can be mapped to the directed case can be read about [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/496389.html).

---

Note, as mentioned in the comments, this may be overkill as a maximal spanning tree may solve this problem. It may require a proof to show that it does however.

Answer (score 0):

If an undirected graph is acyclic, then it's a tree or forest.

If you want to remove the lightest set of edges that will leave you with a forest, then you'll be left with the *maximum* weight forest.

To find the maximum weight forest, apply [Kruskal's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) for finding the minimum spanning tree, but negate the edge weights first, or equivalently just sort the edges in descending order.

Then just choose the remaining edges to get the set to remove.